# Gstreamer rtsp error

Tags: linux, gstreamer, rtsp

I want to get ip camera video stream by gstreamer:
`gst-launch-1.0  rtspsrc location=rtsp://user:pass@192.168.81.32:554/live/ch00_0 ! rtph264depay ! autovideosink`

but get this error
`Установка конвейера в состояние PAUSED…

Конвейер работает и не требует состояния PREROLL…

Установка конвейера в состояние PLAYING…

New clock: GstSystemClock

ОШИБКА: из элемента /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0: Internal data flow error.

Дополнительная отладочная информация:

gstrtspsrc.c(4206): gst_rtspsrc_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0:

streaming task paused, reason not-negotiated (-4)

Execution ended after 54503440 ns.

Установка конвейера в состояние PAUSED...

Установка конвейера в состояние READY…

Установка конвейера в состояние NULL…

Освобождение конвейера…`

i think this is a main proplem
`ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0: Internal data flow error.`

my system is gentoo 3.5.7

Answer (score 0):

You've got wrong pipeline. The correct one is:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://user:pass@192.168.81.32:554/live/ch00_0 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! decodebin ! autovideosink
```

or

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://user:pass@192.168.81.32:554/live/ch00_0 ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! autovideosink
```

As you need to decode the h264 stream before displaying it.
Here are principal chains for media to use:

1. Decoding: encoded src -> demuxer -> decoder -> sink
2. Encoding: raw src(ie simple webcam) -> encoder -> muxer -> sink

Also, check the way to set up auth for rtspsrc. I'm not shure about this, but maybe the only correct one is:
rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.81.32:554/live/ch00_0 user-id=user user-pw=password

Comment: I think he may need the 'videoconvert' between 'decodebin' and 'autovideosink'